# How do I (very approximately) generalize the name of the color based in it's CMYK or RGB numbers?

Tags: image-processing, colors, rgb, cmyk

I am processing an image pixel by pixel and I need to get name of the color for each pixel. I have these main color names: **yellow, magenta, cyan, red, green, blue, white, black**.
I also have RGB and CMYK numbers of each pixel. How would I approximate the color of the pixel to one of the above based on those numbers? It does not need to be precise, just a very general approximation. Is there any maths that I can do with RGB or CMYK to determine that? I would rather prefer a simple solution than a precise one.

Comment: You're asking how to tell whether a color is mainly **yellow** given the **cyan**, **magenta**, **yellow** and **black** components of the color? Have you at least tried to do this?

Comment: Well, for example i have a pixel with RGB(70,200,220). How do i determine whether it is considered yellow or magenta or cyan, etc..

Comment: What are the CMYK values for that color?

Comment: it would be (68%, 9%, 0%, 14%) for this particular one

Comment: So what color do you think that is?

Comment: Well, this one is pretty obviously cyan to the eye, and I do not doubt my eyes. The thing is that I need to programmatically determine that. Use some kind of calculations and output the name of the color having just the RGB (That i can also convert to CMYK if that helps)

Comment: If you were a little bit more forthcoming about what you are trying to do, I suspect you might get a better answer. Let's say your image is a fairly smallish (by modern standards) 1080p image at 1920x1080 pixels. What are you going to do with a list of  2.073 million approximate colour names?

Comment: I need to find the percentages of the colors that this image has. I need an output like this: _this image is 23% white, 11% yellow_, etc...

Comment: I can't tell if you're looking at an image of the color or the CMYK values. So let me suggest this: if you take the CMYK values and convert the maximum value to 1 and the minimum value to 0. Then, for the other two colors, assign them 1 or 0 based on whether their value is closer to the max or the min. Now you have a table of 16 possible values that you should be able to map to your 8 colors.

Comment: Great idea, combining that and another solution to discover blacks and whites more reliably seems to do the work @beaker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take this as a starting image:

[image]

Now, make a map of all the colours that we want to look for, bearing in mind that **ImageMagick** uses X11 colornames where `green` is named `lime`:

```
magick xc:black xc:white xc:red xc:lime xc:blue xc:cyan xc:magenta xc:yellow +append map.png
```

That makes this - which I have magnified because it is only 8 pixels wide and 1 pixel tall:

[image]

Now, we just ask **imageMagick** to map all the pixels in the original image to whatever colour is nearest in the colours in our map:

```
magick artistic-swirl.jpg +dither -remap map.png result.png
```

[image]

Now we look at the distribution of pixels in the colormap of the result:

```
magick identify -verbose result.png | grep -A9 Histogram
```

**Output**

```
 Histogram:
      5063: (0,0,0) #000000 black
     40831: (0,0,255) #0000FF blue
      2831: (0,255,0) #00FF00 lime
     44027: (0,255,255) #00FFFF cyan
     61648: (255,0,0) #FF0000 red
     29828: (255,0,255) #FF00FF magenta
     38729: (255,255,0) #FFFF00 yellow
     27043: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF white
```

And we can see there are 5063 pixels that are black, and 40831 pixels that are blue... and so on.

Note that you can do all this with `wand` which is a Python binding to **ImageMagick**.

Comment: Pastel colors are all mapped to white, but a person would call pastel green as green, not white. “Nearest” in RGB space is definitely not how humans classify colors. Still, I don’t have a better solution… :D

Comment: @CrisLuengo It was clearer before when I used Paddington bear as the image, but apparently I can't use that image any more... ‍♂️ You can see the edit history.

Comment: Were you asked to remove that picture? Wow! Crazy!

Answer (score 0):

While the other solution posted will work for KNOWN names, take a look at models and papers like [this](https://github.com/airalcorn2/Color-Names) one to actually generalize and understand how to translate (even) unknown colors to useful names.

Edit: Even though this isn't what OP wanted, I ended up spending a couple of hours to wire it all up to work easily within Docker/VSCode. See [here](https://gist.github.com/aniongithub/348752bfc2bc432fbdb80b320015717a) for a way to quickly get up and running with this repository.

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: Not what I needed at the moment, but a very interesting solution nevertheless! Will take a look